# Laravel model query with only certain columns

Tags: mysql, laravel, select

I want to make a query that gets all the users from table "users" and i need to have only user.id.

```
$users = User::all();
```

this will get the whole model User but this is a real performance issue for my app. There is too much data going through.

I need to append some data for each user so i can calculate the working hours.

So the question is how to fetch all users without any other data except $user->id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the certain columns, I think this is best:

```
$users = User::select('id')->get();
```

See [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects).

Comment: Code is tested and working fine, why down vote here???? Read carefully given link first.

Comment: `how to fetch all users without any other data except $user->id`, your code returns collection of User objects, test it.

Comment: @Addweb It seems some newbie have read bullcrap about strategic downvoting. Your code works just fine. Upvoted.

Comment: i am still testing it

Comment: @patryk-uszynski Focus on OP's question part `$user->id?`. It does not mean that Object/Array...

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd sorry, this question is a bit unclear `this will get the whole model User but this is a real performance issue`, `i need to have only user.id`

Comment: @patryk-uszynski It's ok, ask to OP for you doubt from question.

Comment: @lewis4u: Working?

Comment: @lewis4u Glad to help you...!

Answer (score 2):

```
$name = DB::table('users')->select('id')->get();
```

Comment: This doesn't return the user model but only the id's from users. Almost same as pluck!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) method:

```
$users = User::pluck('id');
```

> The pluck method retrieves all of the values for a given key

Comment: Will this work with model? I thought pluck is helpler for collections

Comment: Yes it works, because Eloquent has `pluck()` method too.

Comment: Where? https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html

Comment: this will only return the collection of all user->id...and then when i try to add some new property i get an error "Applying to non Object"

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin yes i needed only ID but returned as an object

Comment: @lewis4u I thought you need only IDs. If you need to update multiple rows at once there is a better way to do that instead of getting collection of users and updating them one by one.

Answer (score -1):

Getting all User objects with `id` only:

```
$users = User::select('id')->get();
```

---

Getting all `id` as straight int value

According to documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects

**Specifying A Select Clause** (most efficient)

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('id')->get();
```

**Retrieving A Single Column From A Row** (but this will process all columns)

```
$name = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->pluck('name');
```